# How to close a popup with ease?

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm still learning JavaScript and i am giving myself a few exercises. I have created a small popup like div (since not sure how to create an actual popup) and it works fine. However, i can't figure out how to close the div slowly with transition, but it closes instantly.

```
The code is located below:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wabb5x8e/2/

Comment: It would be better if you could paste your code into the question itself

Comment: Remove the css property dispaly: none and replace it with opacity:0. Because the display property does not support any animation transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code from w3schools but this is what you want. W3schools is a great site for beginners so check javascript and jquery tutorial

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide(1000);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Hide</button>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, i'll try to use this in a few mins, but i'm learning from Colt on Udemy and this is my small project. Was using W3Schools a lot, but tried to do this with vanilla js. I'll try this, give me a few mins.

Comment: You can put the script with src and the script with the actual code straight to your html file and change the id of $("p") to the id of the div you want to hide. I think its the simplest thing you can try.

Comment: Hey man, it's working now, tnx :). One more question, when i close it, it closes it's not closing normally, but, like, going up and left. How can i make it so that it closes by going up? Like a transition effect.

Comment: yes you can add another script but this time call show(). So when you click the button again it will pop up the same hidden div.

Comment: No, i'm trying to create something like a popup. First i tried to edit alert(); on js, but i wasn't able to do that. Then i created a div that will disappear when clicked on yes and will not show until you reload the page. So the idea is that i create something that will ask you did you did something? if no, redirect to a specific link, if yes, it will disappear. This works fine, but when i click on yes, it goes up and left when disappearing. Is there a way to control the way it closes? Like an animation...

Comment: I can't really understand the behavior you want to achieve I am sorry. So the solution I gave you solved one step of the behavior you want ?

Comment: Yeah it did. Ty for that :). Just trying to find out is there a way to control the way something closes, is it like fading away, disappearing like when you turn on or off the TV, Or, like, when you close a window on Mac or minimize on Windows, it has that animation that it's going up to the close button or animate to the start tab. Not sure how to explain it better...

Comment: In w3schools in the link a sent you before there are also fadeIn() and fadeOut() functions check if this can help you. I really can't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey man, don't sweat it. Not sure how to explain better. Ty anyway :)

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: Here is the fiddle. Check the way it closes when you click on yes. If you still don't understand, don't worry. https://jsfiddle.net/wabb5x8e/5/. I would like for the closing animation to change to something else.

Comment: Yes I think you can change the hide or fade animation ... Haha this is the way I know of

Comment: Lol, np :). Cheers mate